# Windows 10 Lenovo T530 w/ docking station and multiple monitors

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a Lenovo T530 w/ docking station running Windows 10 and I wanted to run dual monitors.  I already had a Samsung S27B350 which is HDMI and I bought a Dell U2414H with Displayport In/Out and HDMI out.  I had read that you can run the HDMI monitor at the end of the chain with the Dell monitor connected by Displayport, but it is not working.  I've hooked it up multiple ways including using a Displayport/HDMI adapter connected as Displayport out of the Dell and HDMI in on the Samsung.  It would be great if I can use the Samsung monitor, but appears doubtful.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

No luck. No configuration (integrated/Optimus) of T530 supports MST (daisy-chaining), which was introduced in Display Port 1.2 . They are all version 1.1 instead.
You can however connect them through DVI and Display Port -> DVI/HDMI cables separately. Not sure about HDMI option, but DVI cable doesn't do any conversion since these interfaces are pin compatible.
src:
https://communities.intel.com/thread/38524
https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/549145/driver-319-32-nvs-5200m-dell-u2713d-dp-1-2-daisy-chain-mst-in-debian/